# How to only Allow Numeratic enert into the Console

Tags: vb.net, console

If I am using `Console.ReadLine()` within the console It reads the line just entered but I want to perform a function only allowing my user to enter an integer into the console.

Is this possible?

Any Help Will Be Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop and use `Integer.TryParse` to valid the input.

```
Dim value As Integer
Do
    Console.Write("Would you be so kind to enter an integer: ")
Loop Until Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), value)
```

You can of course sophisticate this further, refine it a bit more. Ex: show an error if it is a wrong value etc. Code example:

```
Console.Write("Would you be so kind to enter an integer: ")
Dim value As Integer
While Not Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), value)
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR! Invalid integer.")
    Console.Write("Would you be so kind to enter an integer: ")
End While
```

And so you go on (you can add a max count, stop the execution, whatever you feel like).